# How can I declare a function as local in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have certain scripts that are meant to be sourced from within an interactive shell. I have some functions that I would like to have scoped locally so they are not visible or cannot be overridden in the shell in which the script was sourced.

For example:

```bash
_local_func() {
   # Do stuff useful to this script, but cannot be called in a shell that sources this script
}

util_func() {
   # Callable by a shell that sources this script
   _local_func
}
```

Comment: I removed the bash tag, bash != zsh

Comment: While there is the concept of a local variable, there are no local functions. Furthermore, you can not protect a function from being deleted or redefined by some malevolent user. To protect against accidental deletion, think about a naming scheme which simulates namespaces, for example by prefixing the function name with the name of the file the function is defined in. A function in file xyz could be named for instance `xyz::func`.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if namespacing would be the last result. I like the idea of using `::` in the name though!

If you'd like to convert your reply to an answer I can mark that as the solution.